# Homotopic family of curves

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I stumbled over the following question.

Imagine we have a two homotopic curves on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^1$ namely $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$. Then we can write them as $\gamma_{i}(t) = e^{i \alpha_i (t)}$ for some function $\alpha_i$. Both paths satisfy $\gamma_1(0)= \gamma_2(0) = -1$ and $\gamma_1(1)=\gamma_2(1)=1.$ Can we conclude from this that the difference $\alpha_2(1)-\alpha_2(0) = \alpha_1(1)-\alpha_1(0)$?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Yes. Use the covering space lifting property.

Comment: @MikeMiller would you mind explaining what you mean exactly and post it as an answer?

Comment: Do you know the lifting lemma for covering spaces? Do you know the homotopy lifting lemma for covering spaces? If not, these are things that are in any textbook that covers fundamental group and covering spaces; that would be an excellent place to start.